# filter not working for date column more than 3 months

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am trying to put 3 filters in 3 columns, in which one is resource name, the second is status, the third is date. For each resource name, I need to find a ticket which was created 3 months before the current month, and status column should have 2 values, "New" and "Open". I wrote the below code, but it is giving me 0 result in return. If I am changing the 3rd filter criteria to ">" & premier_jour_3, it is showing me results before than 3 months and the latest ones after premier_jour_3. If premier_jour_3 = 01/11/2017, it is showing the records with date "07/09/2017  17:59:00" and "31/07/2017  10:35:00"

```
   premier_jour_3 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 3, 1)
With Worksheets("general_report")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:R100000").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter

    Worksheets("general_report").Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ResourceName", Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("general_report").Range("F1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("Opened", "New"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Worksheets("general_report").Range("H1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & premier_jour_3, Operator:=xlAnd
    row_cnt_nt_upd = Evaluate("=subtotal(3,A:A)") - 1
End With
```

Comment: What is the date format in the cells?

Comment: Both date and time is being displayed. Its like this -"06/11/2017  13:51:00". But when I am putting the filter manually in the excel, it is being displayed by year and then month and then time. Like/ 2018 -> February -> 23 -> 7

Comment: Nice of you to provide an ambiguous datetime format. I'll assume that is MDY not DMY.

Comment: I am sorry. It is DMY actually. Please look at the other example - "14/02/2018  16:23:00"

Comment: It is showing me records of previous year than premier_jour_3. Example I can see records of Oct, 2016. but not the ones before premier_jour_3 of the same year.

Answer (score 0):

The .AutoFilter likes its criteria in strings. In the case of dates, this string must be in the EN-US format of `mm/dd/yyyy` or MDY regardless of regional settings.

```
premier_jour_3 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 3, 1)

With Worksheets("general_report")
    if .AutoFilterMode  then .AutoFilterMode = False
    with .Range("A1:R100000")
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ResourceName"
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("Opened", "New"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=format(premier_jour_3, "\<mm/dd/yyyy") 

        row_cnt_nt_upd = Evaluate("=subtotal(3,A:A)") - 1
    end with
End With
```

Comment: Well, I just built a full sample mockup with data and aside from the fact that I missed a single comma, it does work.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Addendum: *'In the case of dates, this string must be in the EN-US format of `mm/dd/yyyy` or MDY regardless of regional settings.'*