# how to put value between <> in filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date column, from which I have to fetch records which will be between  the first day of last month and before the first day of current month. I wrote the below code, but I am not getting how can I apply it in filter.

```
premier_jour_lt_fixed = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1)
dernier_jour_lt_fixed = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
 With Worksheets("sheet1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:R100000").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("O1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<" & dernier_jour_lt_fixed And ">" & premier_jour_lt_fixed, Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="resname", Operator:=xlAnd
```

I am confused if I should apply if else loop, or if I can directly put the value in filter. Obviously the one which I have put in filter is wrong. If anyone knows please help, how can I put it in filter.

Answer (score 4):

use `Criteria2` parameter of `AutoFilter` method:

```
Worksheets("general_report").Range("O1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<" & dernier_jour_lt_fixed, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">" & premier_jour_lt_fixed
```

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("O1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<" & dernier_jour_lt_fixed, criteria2:=">" & premier_jour_lt_fixed, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Thanks. But its not giving me the result. Its displaying 0 record for the same.

Comment: Record yourself doing this manually then look at the generated code and reproduce the criteria formatting.

Comment: See [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944907/filter-not-working-for-date-column-more-than-3-months/48945242#48945242).

Comment: The last question is sorted now. I am able to change the format of the date. But when I am applying this filter, for first day of last month and first day of current month, still no results are being displayed. When applying the filter individually, "premier_jour_lt_fixed " is working fine. But, no results are being displayed for "dernier_jour_lt_fixed" filter. Results greater than first day of previous month is displaying result, but not less than first day of current month.

Comment: For my last question, I am able to change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy.